# Java AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding encryption to crypto-js decryption

Tags: javascript, java, cryptography, aes, cryptojs

Backend Using Below Java code for the AES Encryption.

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;



/**
 * This example program shows how AES encryption and decryption can be done in Java.
 * Please note that secret key and encrypted text is unreadable binary and hence 
 * in the following program we display it in hexadecimal format of the underlying bytes.
 * @author Jayson
 */
public class AESEncryption {

    /**
     * 1. Generate a plain text for encryption
     * 2. Get a secret key (printed in hexadecimal form). In actual use this must 
     * by encrypted and kept safe. The same key is required for decryption.
     * 3. 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


        String plainText = "rajaram";
        String keyText ="test123";
        SecretKey secKey = getSecretEncryptionKey(keyText);
         System.out.println("secKey:" + secKey);

        byte[] cipherText = encryptText(plainText, secKey);
        String decryptedText = decryptText(cipherText, secKey);

        System.out.println("Original Text:>>>> " + plainText);
        System.out.println("AES Key (Hex Form):>>>> "+bytesToHex(secKey.getEncoded()));
        System.out.println("Encrypted Text (Hex Form):>>>> "+bytesToHex(cipherText));
        System.out.println("Descrypted Text:>>>> "+decryptedText);

    }



  public static SecretKey getSecretEncryptionKey(String keyText) throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(getKey(keyText), "AES");
        return keySpec;
    }


  public static byte[] getKey(String keyStr) {
        byte[] key = null;
        try {
            key = (keyStr).getBytes("UTF-8");
            MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            key = sha.digest(key);
        System.out.println("SHA-1 key" + key);  
            key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
        System.out.println("copyOf SHA-1 16 key" + key);        
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     System.out.println("getKey" + key);
        return key;
    }

    /**
     * Encrypts plainText in AES using the secret key
     * @param plainText
     * @param secKey
     * @return
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    public static byte[] encryptText(String plainText,SecretKey secKey) throws Exception{
        // AES defaults to AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding in Java 7
        Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

    System.out.println("ENCRYPT_MODE:" + Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE);
        aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secKey);
    System.out.println("plain Text getBytes:" + plainText.getBytes());
        byte[] byteCipherText = aesCipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());
    System.out.println("byte Cipher Text:" + byteCipherText);
        return byteCipherText;
    }

    /**
     * Decrypts encrypted byte array using the key used for encryption.
     * @param byteCipherText
     * @param secKey
     * @return
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    public static String decryptText(byte[] byteCipherText, SecretKey secKey) throws Exception {
        // AES defaults to AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding in Java 7
        Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        aesCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secKey);
        byte[] bytePlainText = aesCipher.doFinal(byteCipherText);
        return new String(bytePlainText);
    }

    /**
     * Convert a binary byte array into readable hex form
     * @param hash
     * @return 
     */
    private static String  bytesToHex(byte[] hash) {
        return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(hash);
    }
}
```

Above Clas  O/P:

```
getKey[B@6d06d69c
secKey:javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@fffe8c0a
ENCRYPT_MODE:1
plain Text getBytes:[B@34340fab
byte Cipher Text:[B@2aafb23c
Original Text:>>>> rajaram
AES Key (Hex Form):>>>> 7288EDD0FC3FFCBE93A0CF06E3568E28
Encrypted Text (Hex Form):>>>> 8E441411D9890BED64BD7931DE3230C3
Descrypted Text:>>>> rajaram
```

But I am unable to decryption using crypto-js.

Crypto-js code example for the frondend:

```
var bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt("8E441411D9890BED64BD7931DE3230C3", "test123", { mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7 });

var plaintext = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
alert(plaintext);
```

JS fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/baxfk6tw/

Anyone, crypto-js how to add SHA-1 16 key with AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding, Please suggest me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what the link is between the Java class and the JavaScript snippet. Can you please explain?

Comment: Java class using for the AES encryption, CryptoJS using for decryption!.

Comment: Ok, then what does "But I am unable to decryption using crypto-js." mean? You get an error? Wrong output? Please, include some more detail in your question.

Comment: I am getting empty value while decrypting

Comment: @rustyx can u please check and update the  fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rajaramtt/rbh0wkej/

Answer (score 5):

You Java version does the following:

- Hash the password once with SHA1, then take the first 16 bytes as the key.
- Encrypt plaintext UTF-8 bytes with AES-128, ECB mode, PKCS7 padding.
- Convert ciphertext to Hex.

So to **decrypt** it with CryptoJS you need to repeat the same steps:

```js
var ciphertext = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("8E441411D9890BED64BD7931DE3230C3");
var pwhash = CryptoJS.SHA1(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("test123"));
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(pwhash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex).substr(0, 32));

var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({
    ciphertext: ciphertext
 }, key, {
    mode:     CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
    padding:  CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});

var plaintext = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

$('#result').text(plaintext);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.js"></script>

<h2 id="result">
```

---

For reference, **encryption** using CryptoJS might look like this:

```js
var plaintext = "rajaram";
var pwhash = CryptoJS.SHA1(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("test123"));
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(pwhash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex).substr(0, 32));

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, key, {
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});

var ciphertext = encrypted.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);

$('#encrypted').text(ciphertext);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.js"></script>

<h2 id="encrypted">
```